# Docker solution to distribute the file contents among multiple containers and consolidate the outputs to one file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have dataset with one million records. I need to use a ML model to run predictions on these 1 million records and create a new predicton dataset. My current solution/approach is to dockerize the prediction logic in to one single container. But given the scale of input records my solution of one container is not scalable.

My current thought process is as follows:
Depending upon the size of the input dataset, i want to dynamically create multiple docker containers so that each container can predict some portion of the dataset. Finally i want to consolidate the predictions from the all the containers in to one final file.

The implementation approach i am thinking is as follow:

(1) I want to create a master container that should have the logic to  divide the dataset in to multiple smaller files and then
(2) Depending upon the number of smaller files, i want to dynamically create those many number of containers and mount each container with a smaller file [This smaller file contains a portion of the bigger dataset]. 
(3) Finally i want to consolidate the outputs from these multiple containers in to one final file. I also want to preserve the order of the output records.

How would i achieve the above functionality? 
Can one docker container create another docker container?
How does one docker container keep track of multiple containers which it has created?
How to consolidate outputs of multiple containers in to one final single file at the master container?

Comment: [Trying to distribute data processing across a cluster and then aggregate it in master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792927/trying-to-distribute-data-processing-across-a-cluster-and-then-aggregate-it-in-m/60794582#60794582) is pretty similar and I have a generic answer there; does this approach help you?  (Using Docker, on its own, doesn't address this problem, but it can be a good way to run some number of identical workers.)

Comment: Thanks David. But i am looking for a complete generic docker solution, something similar to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000720/distribute-files-between-multiple-docker-containers. The solution should look at the size of the dataset and should decide on dynamically creating the workers (docker containers), managing the workers and consolidating the outputs from them.

Comment: Docker on its own can't do this.  One container can't create other containers without potentially having unrestricted root-level access over the whole system; if it does create other containers, it's responsible for keeping track of them, cleaning them up, and doing whatever data management is required.  I'd suggest coming up with a good solution that doesn't involve Docker, and possibly using Docker as a packaging mechanism if that makes sense.